# DataGridView with covariance?

Tags: c#, datagridview, covariance

I have code like below (I've generified and reduced it to represent just the issue at hand). The code works, that is it takes in a `DataGridView.DataSource` and ulitmately, using `EPPlus`, outputs the data to an Excel file. My question  relates to covariance and how to use it, I think.

So you see it builds `newList` based on the type that it has found in the `DataSource`. Then a little further down it adds the data using the Properties, `someClassObject.Name, .Address and .Phone` that are unique to this type.

My problem is that there are about 75 different classes that could be passed in through the `DataGridView` parameter. Each class has its own unique properties (i.e. not necessarily Name, Address, Phone) though all of the objects in given `DataGridView.DataSource` are of the same class.

I could have a **giant** switch statement based on `type.FullName` and then each would have its own for loop to assign the Property values to the cell. That would work but would be incredibly cumbersome. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public void openExcelReport(ref DataGridView dataGridView, bool bolSave = false, bool bolOpen = true, string pageTitle = "EXPORTED DATA")
{
    // put dataGridView.DataSource into a List
    object firstItem = null;
    var myDataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;
    var myList = ((System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource)dataGridView.DataSource).List;
    firstItem = ((System.Collections.IList)myList)[0]; 
    var type = firstItem.GetType();

    Type PROJECT1_TYPE = typeof(Project1.SomeClass);
    Type PROJECT2_TYPE = typeof(Project2.SomeOtherClass); // many more of these

    dynamic newList = null;

    if (type.FullName.Equals(PROJECT1_TYPE.FullName))
    {
        newList = new List<Project1.SomeClass>();
        foreach (Project1.SomeClass someClassObject in myList)
        {
            newList.Add(someClassObject);
        }
    }

    ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
    using ((package)) // use EPPlus
    {
        // Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1");

        // Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1

        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("FirstColumn", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("SecondColumn", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ThirdColumn", typeof(string));

        dataTable.Columns[0].AutoIncrement = true;

        var column_id = 0;
        foreach (Project1.SomeClass someClassObject in "FirstColumn")
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

            dataRow["FirstColumn"] = someClassObject.Name;
            dataRow["SecondColumn"] = someClassObject.Address;
            dataRow["ThirdColumn"] = someClassObject.Phone

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);

            column_id += 1;

        }

        // worksheet is now populated, so save Excel File     
        ...

}
```

Comment: For the classes that you are passing in, could you modify those to implement an interface that has a `GetDataRow()` (or something similar) function on it so that you can have that code in the class implementation itself, then in here you just do `dataTable.Rows.Add(someClassObject.GetDataRow())`. And be done with it. This would keep you from needing a `switch` or `if/else` block as the particulars for generating the `DataRow` are directly associated with the class containing the would-be columns as properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the `DataRow` creation within this function, you could move it out to the class implementations using a common interface to enforce it, for instance:

```
public interface DataRowConvertable
{
    DataRow GetDataRow();
}

public class SomeClass : DataRowConvertable
{
    public SomeClass() { }
    public SomeClass(string name, string address, string phone)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public DataRow GetDataRow()
    {
        DataRow row = GetDataTable().NewRow();
        row["Name"] = this.Name;
        row["Address"] = this.Address;
        row["Phone"] = this.Phone;
        return row;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("SomeClassTable");
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Phone", typeof(string));
        return table;
    }
}
```

You could take it further, but this should give you a good alternative and a place to start. You can either leave the `GetDataTable` function public, and use that as well to create your table instance, or make it private and only use it internally. I would opt for the former and use that in your function to initialize the table before filling it. You could even get rid of the `static` modifier and add it to your interface, but I prefer the static usage of it in this instance since it is not reliant on the instance of the class and the data involved, only on the structure.

Either way, you could then change the code you have above to look like this:

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1");
System.Data.DataTable dataTable = Project1.SomeClass.GetDataTable();

foreach (Project1.SomeClass someClassObject in myList)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(someClassObject.GetDataRow());
}
```

If you need an incremented `id` column, you could easily add that in the `GetDataTable`/`GetDataRow` functions and update them just as you were above.

This is just a quick example, it could very likely be cleaned up and optimized some, but it still conveys the idea. Hope it helps you out some.

Comment: Thanks. I was so focused on "covariance" that I didn't consider anything else. I will try implementing this and get back to you.